# How to create functions like wp_head()?

Tags: php, function

How to create functions like `wp_head()`?

Here I have three functions:

- `add_css()` - to call the css file to the head tag
- `add_script()` - to call a javascript file into the head tag
- `render_head()` - to display the results of both the above functions

when I call the function `add_css("path/to/style.css")` or `add_script("path /to/javascript.js")` in the body tag or wherever, it will look like this in the head tag by calling `render_head()`:

```
    <link href ="path/to/style.css">
    <script src ="path/to/javascript.js"></script>
```

What should I do to make it that way?

Comment: Why not try to make one first, maybe paste your attempt, something like that...

Comment: Maybe a wordpress custom function?

Comment: @Rasclatt I've tried, but when I tried to show them there is not anything that appears. http://pastebin.com/fJkbws5v

Comment: @claudios sorry, i can't understand what you mean :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want to create a Wordpress-like feature. The question is a little broad and can be primarily opinion-based so this is by no means the only way to do it, but one of many. Wordpress likes to use globals so something similar to this might work like you are describing:

**/classes/RenderEngine.php**

```
class RenderEngine
    {
        // These are just some containers
        private static  $renderer;
        private static  $topage;
        private static  $headElement;
        // This will save to a header array
        public static function addToHeader($value,$type)
            {
                self::$renderer[$type][]    =    $value;
            }
        // This saves to a separate array that can be used to pull
        // specific types of element
        public  static  function saveTo($val,$type)
            {
                self::$headElement[$type]   =   $val;
            }
        // This assembles the css/js arrays and implodes the layout(s)
        public static function getLayout()
            {
                if(!isset(self::$renderer))
                    self::$renderer =   array();

                ob_start();
                foreach(self::$renderer as $type => $val) {
                    if($type == 'js')
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.implode('"></script>'.PHP_EOL.'<script type="text/javascript" src="',$val).'"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
                    elseif($type == 'css')
                        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.implode('" />'.PHP_EOL.'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="',$val).'" />'.PHP_EOL;
                }
                self::$topage   =   ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();

                return self::$topage;
            }
        // This will try and fetch any registered elements
        public  static  function getElement($type)
            {
                return (!empty(self::$headElement[$type]))? self::$headElement[$type] : false;
            }
    }
```

**/functions/functions.php**

```
// General function to add the layout array(s)
function add_element($value,$type)
    {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $spot)
                \RenderEngine::addToHeader($spot,$type);
        }
        else
            \RenderEngine::addToHeader($value,$type);
    }
// Uses the element array to add css
function add_css($value)
    {
        add_element($value,'css');
    }
// Uses the element array to add js
function add_script($value)
    {
        add_element($value,'js');
    }
// This adds to our general array
function add_header_title($value)
    {
        \RenderEngine::saveTo($value,'title');
    }
// This renders the header
function render_header()
    {
        // Start a buffer to cache the string
        ob_start();
        // Don't store the html in the function, rather include it
        include(__DIR__.'/../renderlib/render_header.php');
        // Save the string
        $data   =   ob_get_contents();
        // Clear the buffer
        ob_end_clean();
        // Return the layout string
        return $data;
    }
```

**/renderlib/render_header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title><?php echo \RenderEngine::getElement('title'); // Retrieve stored element ?></title>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php echo \RenderEngine::getLayout(); // Render the css/js ?>
</head>
```

**To use:**

```
// Load relevant helpers
require_once(__DIR__.'/classes/RenderEngine.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/functions/functions.php');
// Add elements
add_css(array('/file/test/style.css','/file/test/style2.css'));
add_css('/file/test/style3.css');
add_script(array('/js/script.js','/js/script1.js'));
add_script('/js/script2.js');
add_header_title('Page Title');
// Render header
echo render_header();
```

**Gives you:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page Title</title>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/file/test/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/file/test/style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/file/test/style3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script2.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be more elegant but this works:

```
<?php

class Head {
    public $tohead="<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html>\n    <head>\n";
    public function addcss($css) {
        $this->tohead .= "      <link rel='stylesheet' href='$css'>\n";
    }

    public function addscript($js) {
        $this->tohead .= "      <script type='text/javascript' src='$js'></script>\n";
    }

    public function render() {
        $this->tohead .= "    </head>\n";
    }
}

$head = new Head;
$head->addcss('/assets/css/my.css');
$head->addscript('/assets/js/my.js');
$head->render();
echo $head->tohead;
```